# Inconsistency with status code when scraping a site (200 or 403)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape `seekingalpha.com` news section as a personal project.
However, it seems I am not able to successfully emulate a browser as once I get to page 8 or so,I get the `403 forbidden output code`. If I open up my browser in private mode, I am able to browse all of the pages manually, so my IP isn't being blocked.

I am using `Requests` and `Beautifulsoup` in `Python3.8`

I have:

- Added a legit User Agent as well as tried random user-agents
- Using Request Session which should be automatically updating cookies, I believe (?)
- Added a Referrer header
- Increased time-delay between requests

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time
import random
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys
import os



class SeekingAlpha():

    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    ua = UserAgent()

    BASE_URL = 'https://seekingalpha.com/'
    NEWS_URL = BASE_URL + 'articles?page={}'


    def __init__(self):
             self.session = requests.Session()
             self.session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11;  Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'

             response =self.session.get(self.BASE_URL)
             response.raise_for_status() 
             self.session.headers['Referrer'] = 'https://seekingalpha.com/'
             print(self.session.headers)
             self.master_urls = []

             for i in range(1,100):        
                page = self.session.get(self.NEWS_URL.format(i))
                time.sleep(random.randint(3,5))
                page.raise_for_status()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
                links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
                links = [link for link in links if link.has_attr("sasource") and link['sasource'] == 'all_articles']
                self.master_urls.extend(links) 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    master_urls = SeekingAlpha()
```

EDIT:

Here is what I see with page 8 via browser (removed headers as not to take up too much space within post):

"
LATEST ARTICLES

HIGHLIGHT:

```
    All
    Top Ideas
    Editors' Picks
    Small-Cap Insight
    Outstanding Contribution
    Most Popular
```

ARTICLES |  NEWS |  TRANSCRIPTS

```
Should I Open A Roth IRA Right Now? That Depends
Charles Lewis Sizemore, CFA • Thu, Apr. 30, 11:15 AM
China Continues To Lead World's Major Equity Regions In 2020
James Picerno • MCHI, SPY, VT• Thu, Apr. 30, 11:09 AM
Gold And Gas: 2 Anti-Recession Trades
Atlas Research • QQQ, UNG, SAND• Thu, Apr. 30, 11:05 AM
Excellent Total Return Bond Funds For Momentum-Based Fixed Income Portfolios
MyPlanIQ • TGMNX, BOND, DLTNX• Thu, Apr. 30, 11:04 AM
NXP's Share Price Already Assumes A Lot Of Growth And Improvement
Stephen Simpson, CFA • MCHP, RNECY, TXN• Thu, Apr. 30, 11:01 AM
[This article is one of the editors' picks] Chart Industries Worth Another Look With LNG Mostly Washed Out
Stephen Simpson, CFA • GTLS• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:53 AM
Dana Incorporated 2020 Q1 - Results - Earnings Call Presentation
SA Transcripts • DAN• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:43 AM
Don't Panic! Coronavirus, GDP, And Unemployment
CFA Institute Contributors • SPY, QQQ, DIA• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:42 AM
Predicting Depressions For Dummies, Part II
John Overstreet • SPY, QQQ, DIA• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:37 AM
Cognex Already Trading On Recovery Prospects
Stephen Simpson, CFA • FANUY, CGNX• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:29 AM
Meritor, Inc. 2020 Q2 - Results - Earnings Call Presentation
SA Transcripts • MTOR• Thu, Apr. 30, 10:28 AM
```

"

Comment: They may be throttling multiple requests.

Comment: Try to access the page 8 url, then print the content (if you haven't already). Read what you see -- that's why it is breaking. As for how to get around that, I don't know.

Comment: @OldWinterton  I have accessed page 8, and I see links to articles. I will update OP.

Comment: Page 8. “Click this button if you are not a robot” was in the html I was looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the random sleep? I assume 3-5 is too low, and a website might shut you down after your 8th request. Either increase it, or if you get a 403 go to sleep and try again after a while.

If you really need that data ASAP, configure a Tor proxy, and use it for a while. (gives you a different external IP - drop your session just in case)

Sometimes if your bot gets too annoying, the website's owner throws you out (at least, that's my experience :-/ ).

Comment: I haven't tried increasing sleep yet, but someone else told me they were able to get to a 100 requests before and it has something to do with headers (though they don't remember the details as it's been a while). Basically it seems the site is using additional headers to verify if you are a browser or not. I **think** (not entirely sure), that they are using redirects to give browser additional information to include within headers. I am a beginner in anything with web-development, so I am not 100 percent sure.